# OS X php / composer problems - reset

Tags: php, macos, composer-php

I'm on OS X and was trying to install phpmetrics via composer, but PHP was too old.
So I tried to update PHP : now everything is broken. Should have RTM more.

A call to composer throws me this kind of error : 
Call to undefined function Symfony\Polyfill\Mbstring\iconv()

After investigation, PHP extensions I had before are now all gone.

Is there a way to reset OS X apache/php so I can get everything back ?
How can I properly delete composer without command line ?

*[censored grumblings about composer*]

Comment: You should strongly consider installing PHP via homebrew. http://brew.sh/

Comment: **[censored grumblings about OSX]** yep for homebrew. Same for apache. Tricky part is to stop the 'shipped' apache from starting automagically all the time. Also, before trying anything in the future, make certain you have the latest composer by issuing 'composer selfupdate' at the command line. Chances are you may have been fooled by that in the first place. Even if you homebrew php now, the shipped apache is hardwired to the shipped php, not the one you just installed.

Comment: You should strongly consider installing PHP / web server on a virtual machine with Linux. In a regular way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start with this. I'm seriously bored by these overcomplicated package managers that never work like they say.

Comment: @FLX Homebrew's basically the OSX standard these days because it's pretty straightforward and tends to work well.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes, I didnt use these a lot, but brew might be the only one that always worked. Phpmetrics is only available on composer. Composer asked me to update PHP, and this was the moment when I started to follow random tutorials and everything went bad... I have know 4-5 php installations in multiple random system path, laughing and crying at same time.

Comment: The PHP binary package from Liip.ch is worth a look (http://php-osx.liip.ch/). Like you I've battled a few different PHP options on OSX (default, XAMPP, brew, etc) and all have had their problems. The Liip package has many useful extensions baked in too.

Comment: Tried liip packaged, works well. Thanks. Just one thing : I had troubles with loading config not corresponding to php.ini. There was a custom ini file (99-liip-developer.ini) overriding some values like memory_limit (RTFM again). Might be good to know.